# PHP DateTime->diff dont works as expected

Tags: php, date, datetime, intervals

I'm trying to use DateTime->diff to get the number of months between two dates. The problem is  I cant understand how works this function. Try this examples, notice that i'm adding one month every output:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-01-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-01-01');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->m
```

Output is 0.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-01-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-02-01');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->m
```

Output is 1.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-01-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-03-01');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->m
```

Output is... 1??? How is this possible?? Month is March, not February. Same error happens in months 6-7

EDIT: Note this question ISNT about February cause this happens in months 6-7

Thanks for you attention.

Comment: Gordon have no idea about this issue. The real answer is:

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-01-01',new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-02-01',new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

Comment: In which case it is a dupe of [PHP's DateTime::Diff gets it wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9695870) or similar questions.

Comment: Yep, it is very easy to search about the solution when YOU ALREADY know the solution, right? :)